# How I can show mouse coordinates only when its on a draw?

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics

If I have plotted a function like `y = sin(x)`, how can I show mouse co-ordinates only when the mouse is on the line of the function?

Comment: if i draw a function like sin(x)
how i can show coordinates only when the mouse on the line?

Comment: `y=Sin(x)` is a continuous function. Also when drawing the function, you need to scale the result. So you should describe how you draw the function and in which points you want to show coordinates. I suppose you have a `PointF[]` array, so do you want to hit test just for these points?

Comment: If you have drawn into a Bitmap you can test with bmp.GetPixel. If you are drawing in the Paint event use Jim's analytical approach. In any other case (ie if you are using control.CreateGraphics()) you are doing the drawing wrong and should correct that first.)

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you've drawn the curve for `sin(x)` by computing the values and plotting the curve. So when `x = 27`, for example, `y` will be some known value. And you drew the curve with `sin(0)` being plotted at some `x,y` coordinate on your window. There's some mapping between the angle `x` and the `x` coordinate on your screen, and between the result of `sin(x)` and the `y` coordinate on your screen.

For example, suppose you generated the value of `sin(x)` for all values between 0 and 180. The results have the range -1 to +1. And you have this mapping:

```
xCoordinate = (int)(2*x);
yCoordinate = (int)((100*y) + 200);
```

Now, if you want to see if the mouse is on the curve, you need to convert the mouse's current `x` coordinate back to an angle. You do that by reversing your translation:

```
x = xCoordinate/2;
```

Now, compute `sin(x)` again and use the translation to determine the `y` coordinate. Compare the result with the mouse's current `y` coordinate. If they're equal, then you're on the curve.

The reason I use the cast to `int` is because otherwise you'll get fractional values and the mouse coordinates are always integers. So your computation of the `y` coordinate might give you 270.71 for `sin(45)`. That will be truncated to 270 when you plot it.